# fgets does not fill the array completely

Tags: c, fgets

I want to read a text file and store it into an array `data[512]`.

Here is the code:

```
char filename = "send.txt";

//Open File
FILE *in_file = fopen("send.txt", "r");

if(in_file == NULL){
    printf("Error : couldn't oepn file");
}

char data[512];
while(fgets(data, sizeof(data), in_file) != NULL){
    printf("read size: %d \n", strlen(data));
    ...    
}
```

Why does `strlen(data)` each time return a different value? Why is `data` in not fully filled?

**EDIT**

When using `fread()` inside a while loop:

```
printf("Start Reading \n" );
memset(&data[0], 0, sizeof(data));
size_t numRead = fread(data,1,sizeof(data),in_file);
printf("numRead: %d \n", numRead );
if(numRead == NULL)
{
    printf(" fread() failed\n");
    return 1;
}              
printf("data size: %d \n", strlen(data));
```

the data size (last line) is not correct!

Sample Textfile (it is ok for all except the first one where `strlen` returns 513 instead of 512):

e Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.e Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.e Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.e Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker. 
Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.e Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux

Comment: use fgetc(), it is not efficient, but you are sure it will be filled.

Comment: show your file contents..

Comment: it it possible to attach file here?

Comment: @H'H  Simply post 4 lines or so of your text file and the `strlen()` output associated with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does `fgets` do:

> The C library function char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream) reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.

So in your code:

```
fgets(data, sizeof(data), in_file);
```

Will read *at most* 511 chars, but it'll stop reading once a new line or an EOF is encountered.
If you want to read as many chars as the `data` array is big, then either read them one by one, using `fgetc`, or call `fgets` in a loop, each time appending the rest of the read data to the end of `data`. An *untested* example:

```
size_t data_len = 0,
    total_len = 0,
    max_len = sizeof data/sizeof *data;//sizeof *data is one, unless you decide to use w_char or something
while ((fgets(data + data_len, max_len - data_len, in_file)) != NULL)
{
    data_len = strlen(data);
    if (data_len >= 511)//==511 should work, but you never know
    {
        total_len += data_len;//keep running total
        data_len = 0;
        printf("%s\n", data);
        data[0] = '\0';//make empty string
    }
}
if (data_len)
    printf("%s\nread size: %zu\n", data, total_len + data_len);
```

Answer (score 3):

fgets() will read until it reaches a newline or the end of file. If your file must have lines separated by newlines of various lengths.

Use [fread()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) instead, it will read as must as you tell it to, unless it hits an end of file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide if this is a text file or a binary file that you are reading. If it is a textfile `fgets` and `strlen` are the right ones, your are reading line by line, and so the length of what is read will differ.

If this is a binary file use `fread`, but then never do `strlen` on the buffer. By coincidence your buffer may have `0` bytes, so these would be interpreted as end-of-string character by `strlen`.

Comment: this is a send.txt text file.It is ok for all except the first one which strlen retrun 513 instead of 512... what could be the reason?

Comment: @H'H: If `strlen` of a `char[512]` is greater than 511 (strings are arrays of chars with a terminating `\0`), you're at risk of invoking UB (Undefined Behavior)

Comment: there is no way of avoiding this??

Comment: @H'H: Sure there is, use `fgets` like I did in my example or use `fread(data, sizeof *data, sizeof data/sizeof *data -1, in_file)` and make sure that `data[511]` is always `\0`. Note the `-1` in the third argument: read _at most_ sizeof array -1 chars, you *have* to leave room for that all-important terminating `\0` char

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks, Now I uderstand it well.